# ASP.NET - Call and handle Web API with multiple different parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API and I have question that can not resolve.

This is my question: how call a Web API that need multiple parameters (stream or object and two or three string)? And how handle this parameters inside Web API?

For example, I have this method in my Web API:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public MyObject Method(Stream s, string first, string second)
    {
        // take the parameters and do something
    }
}
```

Where Stream is a stream of file (or an object in other cases).
How can add all these parameters to client request body? And how take them from there and use in the method?

**EDIT**:
this solution is good?
Here the client:

```
{
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        queryString["first"] = "true";
        queryString["second"] = "false";
        var uri = "https://myapi.com/api/mycontroller/method?" + queryString;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myFile);

        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
           content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("<application/json >");
           response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        }

    }
```

And here the Web API:

```
[HttpPost]
public MyObject Method([FromBody]Stream s, [FromUri]string first, [FromUri]string second)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: you cannot pass multiple parameter to WebApi in this way. use `[FromBody]`

Comment: Ok, thank you! But my first problem is how add the objects to the request body. And in second time how to handle them in the web API method.

Comment: you can use get instead!. if u are particular to use objects explicitly update your post with what u actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebApi does not support to passing multiple parameter in this way, simply you can create a dto/model class and pass that class from body to the method.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Byte[] s {get;set;}
    public string first {get;set;}
    public string second {get;set;}
}
```

WepApi controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Register([FromBody] Foo foo) 
{
    //do something
    return Ok();
}
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to create classes for your each methods. Then you can use like following one, but recommend to use first one.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Register([FromBody]dynamic value)
{
    //convert to attribute
    string first = value.first.ToString();
    string second = value.second.ToString();
}
```

Here is good read: [`Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)`](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: Thank you! If I don't want create an apposite class, use a `Dictionary<string,string>` and serialize every object is a good solution? I read the "Get Started" you post, but in that example the call to web api is made from javascript with Ajax. I would make the call from c#.

Comment: If you don't want to create classes for your each method then there is a second solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I found another solution, I try to write it by editing the message and we see if it's okay like your suggestion

Comment: Sure, will let me know.

Comment: Now you're mashup two questions, first is **Call and handle Web API with multiple different parameters** and second one is **this solution is good?** I suggest you to rollback your change and ask a new question.

Comment: Hope that dose make sense.

Comment: If it's helpful then please, accept this an answer and also refer: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)